# How to get enum key js?

Tags: javascript

i have an enum and in other component i use in this enum but i need the key
and i dont know how to get it

the enum

```
export const AlgorithmType = {
    Bfs: 0,
    Dfs: 1,
    Kruskal: 2,
    Dijkstra: 3,
    BellmanFord: 4,
    IsCircle: 5
}

Object.freeze(AlgorithmType)
```

and the component

```
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange(AlgorithmType[AlgorithmType.Bfs])}>BFS</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange(AlgorithmType.Dfs)} >DFS</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange( AlgorithmType.Dijkstra)} >Dijkstra</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange(AlgorithmType.BellmanFord)} > Belmal-Ford</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange(AlgorithmType.Kruskal)} >Kruskal</Dropdown.Item>
<Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => DataChange(AlgorithmType.IsCircle)} >האם יש מעגל</Dropdown.Item>
```

as you see i tried one wey in bfs and it's not work
i get undefind

thank you!

Comment: The OP might have a look into [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). In addition I highly recommend editing the questions towards more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to find the property name for a given value. It is obvious that Maps or JavaScript objects are designed to work the other way round to quickly find a value for a given key. Getting the key(s) for a given value therefore *in general* requires some looping and is therefore not faster than a linear search in an array.

### In general

In general you could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to find that. There are many ways to solve this problem.

Here one way using `Object.keys()` and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which returns **all keys** for a given value. Keep in mind that in general there could be many keys holding the same value.

If you are just looking for the **first key** that matches a value such as in your case you could use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter()`.

```js
const AlgorithmType = {
    Bfs: 0,
    Dfs: 1,
    Kruskal: 2,
    Dijkstra: 3,
    BellmanFord: 4,
    IsCircle: 5,
  };
  
  /**
   * Find all property names that hold a given value.
   * @param {Object} obj 
   * @param {Array<any>} value 
   * @returns array of all property name holding that value
   */
  function allPropertyNameForValue(obj, value){
      return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === value);
  }

  /**
   * Find the first property name that holds a given value
   * @param {Array<Object>} obj 
   * @param {any | undefined} value 
   * @returns property name that holds the value of undefined if there is no such value
   */
  function propertyNameForValue(obj, value){
    return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value)
}
  
  console.log(propertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, AlgorithmType.Bfs));
  console.log(propertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, AlgorithmType.NotExistingKey));
  console.log(propertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, 4));
  console.log(propertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, 10));

  console.log(allPropertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, AlgorithmType.Bfs));
  console.log(allPropertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, AlgorithmType.NotExistingKey));
  console.log(allPropertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, 4));
  console.log(allPropertyNameForValue(AlgorithmType, 10));
```

#### Values are unique

If you need to lookup multiple values during the course of your program and **each value is unique** you could also create a reverse mapping once and use that to lookup the keys for values in `O(1)`.

```js
const AlgorithmType = {
  Bfs: 0,
  Dfs: 1,
  Kruskal: 2,
  Dijkstra: 3,
  BellmanFord: 4,
  IsCircle: 5,
};

const reverseAlgorithmType = createReverseMap(AlgorithmType);

function createReverseMap(obj){
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((revMap, [k, v]) => (revMap[v] = k, revMap), {});
}

console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[AlgorithmType.Bfs]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[AlgorithmType.NonExistingKey]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[4]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[10]);
```

#### Values are unique and array indices

In your specific case with the values starting at `0` and increasing by one (=> unique) the array indices in the array returned by `Object.keys()` will be equivalent to the actual values and can therefore be used like a map, so another solution would be:

```js
const AlgorithmType = {
  Bfs: 0,
  Dfs: 1,
  Kruskal: 2,
  Dijkstra: 3,
  BellmanFord: 4,
  IsCircle: 5,
};

const reverseAlgorithmType = Object.keys(AlgorithmType);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[AlgorithmType.Bfs]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[AlgorithmType.NonExistingKey]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[4]);
console.log(reverseAlgorithmType[10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(AlgorithmType)[algorithm] - algorithm it's the value of the enum
this is the way

Comment: I doubt it for the (use) case that the `algorithm` value is a string like `'Bfs'`, `'Kruskal'` etc. Why? ... `Object.keys` returns an array of the object's property names (keys). Thus, the only plausible accessor values are integers (or strings representing such integers) in between `0` and the keys-array's `length - 1`. If the latter was true and one has to do `Object.keys(AlgorithmType)[0]` what is all this mapping effort good for?